# CSS linear-gradient of JavaFX barchart

Tags: java, css, javafx, bar-chart, linear-gradients

my current styling pattern is (`{0}` is replaced with bar specific color code)

```
  "-fx-bar-fill: rgb({0});"
+ "-fx-background-color: "
+ "linear (0%,0%) to (0%,100%) "
+ "stops (0%, derive(-fx-bar-fill,-30%)) "
+ "(100%, derive(-fx-bar-fill,-40%)), "
+ "linear (0%,0%) to (0%,100%) "
+ "stops (0%, derive(-fx-bar-fill,80%)) "
+ "(100%, derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%)), "
+ "linear (0%,0%) to (0%,100%) "
+ "stops (0%, derive(-fx-bar-fill,30%)) "
+ "(100%, derive(-fx-bar-fill,-10%));"
+ "-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;"
+ "-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;";
```

This looks like this:

[image: deprecated css styling]

The problem is that I get a parser warning because of deprecated `linear` syntax.
I tried to refactor the styling pattern to `linear-gradient` without changing the result using the [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typelinear-gradient) but I don't get it.
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: I believe the following is equivalent to the first linear gradient: `linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 100%, derive(-fx-bar-fill, -30%) 0%, derive(-fx-bar-fill, -40%) 100%);`.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw for that idea. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. With this syntax I could set some "steps" for the gradient. The big problem is, that these steps only are vertically. I have no idea how to get the horizontal gradient at the border of the bars.

Comment: I was simply providing a single, equivalent gradient in the non-deprecated syntax so you'd have something to compare to in order to finish the conversion, though in hindsight maybe the `;` was confusing. I thought you were only having a problem with the `linear-gradient` syntax but understood the fact you had multiple backgrounds with different insets. If that was not the case, I apologize. However, I'm glad you were able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated version defines three backgrounds.
Each background starts with `linear`.
These backgrounds work like layers.
So the only thing I had to do was to create three backgrounds, too.
My first solution separeted the backgrounds with ; which leads to a parsing error.
The backgrounds have to be separeted by comma.
The border of the bars are created by reducing the drawing area using `-fx-background-insets`.
My final solution is

```
  "-fx-bar-fill: rgb({0});"
+ "-fx-background-color: "
+ "linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 100%, " // start bg1
+ "derive(-fx-bar-fill, -30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, -40%)),"
+ "linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 100%, " // start bg2
+ "derive(-fx-bar-fill, 80%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%)),"
+ "linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 100%, " // start bg3
+ "derive(-fx-bar-fill, 30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, -10%));"
+ "-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;" // reducing drawing area for each bg
+ "-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;"
```